# Multiple outlets between two 3 way switches

Tags: multiway-switch

I have multiple outlets (5) in between two 3-ways. I've gotten the outlet closest to the source switch to work w/ both switches but I need to rewire the rest. I am running one 14/3 on this circuit. These outlets will control shop lights that plug in. I see diagrams with a one outlet config but not multiple. I can draw a diagram if you want one?

Comment: Are you handling these sockets as though they were "lights", all switched at once from both ends? [This would be very dodgy on regs if it were UK but as you call the switches 3-way, I'm assuming US].

Comment: Yes, because my shop lights are plug in. It's US and I'm certain this is allowable.

Comment: No worries, just needed to clarify. US regs always feel very lax to a Brit ;) A standard mains socket must be wired for 13A & cannot be on a lighting circuit. Mains sockets are generally on a ring, lights are spurs. It entails very different wiring setups.

Comment: Can’t do it Not with 14-3 anyway, I run Smurf tube and individual conductors  this is the least expensive way as you need hot, neutral ground and travelers for standard 3 way switches.

Comment: @DaveMG it's allowable, but it forces you to have GFCI protection on the branch, if the receptacles are in a space which requires GFCI protection on receptacles (e.g. garage). And the GFCI device must be readily reachable to test/rese, so "GFCI receptacles on the ceiling" are nope.   Note also garage circuits are usually 20A and that requires #12 to the lights - you can't use #14 to lights unless the breaker is 15A.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to stick with 14/3 instead of using /4 cable, or THHN in ENT ("smurf tube") for that matter?

Comment: No reason ThreePhaseEel other than inexperience. I do want to thank you and EdBeal for the Smurf Tube idea though!

Answer (score 4):

#14 wire is allowed only if the circuit breaker is 15A.  If the breaker is 20A, #12 wire *must* be used.  If you thought "lights get #14" that is false unless the lighting circuit is 15A.  In junction boxes, #14 needs 2.0 cubic inches per wire, and #12 needs 2.25 cubic inches.

Also note that receptacles on a garage or basement ceiling need GFCI *protection*.  They cannot be GFCI receptacles if they are out of easy reach.  In that case, your best bet is to make the box (where power comes in) an XL size 2-gang box, and wire a GFCI *deadfront* before the switch.  Or this circuit can be fed from the "Load" terminals of a GFCI receptacle, but that means the lights will trip if somebody trips the receptacle.   I'll just go ahead and show that in my diagrams, disregard if irrelevant. All protected receptacles need "GFCI Protected" stickers. Really.

### Version 1: /4 cable, ouch

[image]

*Safety ground conductor present in all cables. Not shown.*

This is just not going to work.  Between all lamps you will need switched-hot, neutral, 2 travelers and safety ground. That's not going to happen on /3 cable.  It doesn't have enough wires.

But even if you upgraded to /4 or /2/2 cable, you have a bigger problem:  That's an awful lot of wires in each box.  Since grounds are 4 for the price of 1, that's 9 wires per box, plus 1 count for the cable clamps, plus 2 counts for the receptacle itself.  So that is 12 wire counts.  14 cubic inches with #14 and 27 cubic inches with #12.

These are *big* boxes.  Much bigger than you planned to use.

Also due to NEC 300.3 all wires must be in the same cable - no using two /2's as a substitute for /4.  That means wasting money on a spool of /4 you won't use for anything else.

I do this scheme all the time, but I run individual wires in conduit, so the two traveler wires simply "pass through", and grounds and cable clamps are handled by the conduit. That brings the wire count to a reasonable number.

### Version 2: /3 bypass

[image]

Run the /3 cable straight from switch to switch, bypassing all the boxes.  There is no reason for them to go *through* every lamp box, it's a waste of time, a nightmare to splice, and makes box fill too large. Now we only have 8 wire counts per box, for a more reasonable 16 cubic inches with #14 and 18 with #12.

Run the power into one switch.  From the other, you only need /2 cable to the lamps proper.

### Version 3: /3 cable, no bypass

[image]

Nothing easier. Run /2 from the powered switch to the first lamp. /3 beyond there all the way to the far switch.

How is this going to work? Easy, we're using smart switches, so the switches communicate wirelessly.   The far switch is the "master" which switches the *switched-hot* wire (here: red), and we are simply carrying always-hot (black) and neutral (white) the full length of the circuit to provide power to switches and neutral to lamps.

However this only reduces wire count by 2 compared to version 1, which means you still need 20 cubic inches for #12 or 22.5 cubic inches for #14.

### Version 4: /2 cable, bypass

[image]

In this version we start at the powered switch, run /2 cable to the other switch, bypassing the lamps.  This /2 is "always-hot" and "neutral" and again we are using smart switches.

Then we come back from that switch to the lamps with more /2.  Here, black is "switched-hot" and white is neutral.

### Version 5: all /2, no bypass

[image]

Here we use a smart-switch "master" with a *battery-powered* smart-switch remote.  This may not pass Code everywhere.

We wire this exactly like a *single switch* circuit. Power to the switch, then the black and white from switch to lamps is switched-hot and neutral.

Pair the switch to the battery remote, then stick the remote anywhere you want.  Some battery remotes mount in normal junction boxes (which need no wires to them).

Comment: Reinstate-Monica I do have the shop light circuit on a 15a breaker which is also GFCI protected. Thank you very much for all the great info! I'm really impressed with the caliber of knowledge in this forum and all the folks, even from UK, lending an assist!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to wire a pair of three-way switches to control multiple lights/outlets is to have a hot and neutral at the first switch.

Then you run two traveler wires, together with the neutral to the second switch.

Finally, you run switched hot and neutral from the second switch along all the lights/outlets that need to be controlled by the switches.

Depending on your outlets, you either connect both the incoming and outgoing switched hot and neutral all to the outlet, or you use a pigtail to connect the outlet.

As you can see, electrically speaking, the outlets/lights are not between the switches, but rather on one end, while the permanent hot wire is on the other end. Between the switches you only have a continuous run of the traveler wires.

Comment: Thank you Bart. Very helpful explanation. I'll reread and sketch it out.